# Prove/disprove that For the equation $f(f(x)) + 2f(x) = 8x$, for all x>0, to hold, it is necessary for $f(x)$ to be a linear function.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

For the equation $f(f(x)) + 2f(x) = 8x$, for all x>0. to hold, it is necessary for $f(x)$ to be a linear function.

So far, I've tried plugging in general forms of different functions like quadratic (ax^2+bx+c=0) and other functions in place of f(x) and found that the equality doesn't hold. But, I could find solutions where f(x) was a linear function. So, I've found this proposition to be empirically true.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake - I've tried plugging in general forms of different functions like quadratic (ax^2+bx+c=0) and other functions in place of f(x) and found that the equality doesn't hold. But, I could find solutions where f(x) was a linear function. So, I've found this proposition to be empirically true.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be $1$ when $x \neq 1$, and $2$ for $x=1$. Then $f(f(x))+f(x)$ is equal to $3$ everywhere, hence linear, but $f$ is not linear.

Comment: @radekzak Thank you, but maybe I should have rephrased the question because, in the problem I am trying to use this proposition, g(x) is a non-constant linear function.

Comment: It is easy to tweak radekzak's construction: for example, let $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is not an integer and let $f(x) = x + 1$ if $x$ is an integer.  Then $f(f(x)) - 2f(x) = -x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @user7777777 Most functions are not continuous, let alone analytic.

Comment: @JBL I think I understand. But, I'm unable to get any f(x) to disprove where the coefficient of f(x) is positive. Also, I found the exact coefficient from the question. Can you give an example to disprove? Thanks

Comment: Well, this is completely different kind of a problem now, once you wrote the coefficients and your $g(x)$ is just constant times $x$.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Prove/disprove the following proposition." says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm supposing $f$ is everywhere positive, otherwise this problem doesn't make much sense (you could produce some discontinuous $f$ like in the comments).)

A sketch: let $f^n(x)$ mean $f(f(\ldots f(f(x))))$, where $f$ is composed $n$ times. Choose some positive $x_0$, and let $a_n = f^n(x_0)$. Then, of course, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$. By plugging $x=a_n$ to your equation, you get $a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}=8a_n$.

By standard methods of solving such equations, you get $a_n = \gamma (-4)^n + \delta 2^n$ for some $\gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, you only need to solve the system of equations $\gamma+\delta=x_0$, $-4\gamma+2\delta=f(x_0)$, and then proceed by induction. Hence, if $\gamma \neq 0$, for large $n$ the sequence $a_n$ behaves like $\gamma (-4)^n$. But $a_n$ is always positive, which is a contradiction. Hence $\gamma=0$, so $a_n = 2^n \delta = 2^n x_0$. In particular $f(x_0)=a_1=2x_0$, hence $f(x)=2x$ everywhere.

Comment: Side note: This is a "standard" question and the typical setup is often $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. I'm guessing OP forgot to mention it, and it gives the "everywhere positive" condition that is desired.

Comment: Sometimes it is $\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$, but it is true that the setup occurs in many different problems.